# How check internet connection using Winsock api?

Tags: sockets, delphi, winsock, delphi-10-seattle

I built this code below (based in [**this**](https://toster.ru/q/238981) example) to check if exists connection with internet using `Winsock` api and trying make a GET request to a specific website (*google.com* in my case).

But `WSAGetLastError` returns the error code: **10051**.

How fix this?

```
program Project1;

uses
  Windows, SysUtils, WinSock;

function GetIPFromHostName(const HostName: string): string;
var
  WSAData: TWSAData;
  R: PHostEnt;
  A: TInAddr;
begin
  Result := '0.0.0.0';
  WSAStartup($101, WSAData);
  R := GetHostByName(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(HostName)));
  if Assigned(R) then
  begin
    A := PInAddr(R^.h_Addr_List^)^;
    Result := WinSock.inet_ntoa(A);
  end;
end;

function IsConnectedToInternet: Boolean;
var
  WSAData1: TWSAData;
  SockAddr1: TSockAddr;
  Socket1: TSocket;
begin
  Result := False;

  if WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), WSAData1) <> 0 then
  begin
    Writeln('WinSock error');
    Exit;
  end;

  Socket1 := Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if Socket1 = INVALID_SOCKET then
  begin
    Writeln('socket error');
    Exit;
  end;

  SockAddr1.sin_family := AF_INET;
  SockAddr1.sin_addr.S_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(GetIPFromHostName('google.com')));
  SockAddr1.sin_port := htons(80);

  if Connect(Socket1, SockAddr1, SizeOf(SockAddr1)) <> 0 then
  begin
    Writeln('connection error #', WSAGetLastError);
    Exit;
  end;

  Result := True;

  if CloseSocket(Socket1) <> 0 then
    Writeln('error closing socket');
end;

begin
  IsConnectedToInternet;
  readln;

end.
```

Comment: For one thing, Google sees this type of thing as a denial of service attack and will block you after a short while.  Perhaps that is your issue?  It's not the right way to check your Internet connection anyway.  Winsock is not the solution, there are other Windows specific APIs for getting notified about Internet state changes like those that exist on iOS and Android.

Comment: @AllenDrennan actually, connecting to an Internet server is exactly the best way to determine if an Internet connection is available. Networks can be complicated, and an Internet connection can be obtained in many different ways. Those other APIs you mention are not always accurate/reliable.

Comment: Maybe it's better to try to connect to the actual server you want/need to connect to. I think there are thousands of applications that suddenly refuse to work once Google is down, even though they don't need Google at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler is warning you for your error, on the line you are filling `in_addr` of the `sockaddr_in`:

> W1044 Suspicious typecast of string to PAnsiChar

`inet_addr` expects an ANSI character string. You're typecasting a unicode string to a PAnsiChar and thus passing a malformed string, leading to `connect` unable to find the destination.

replace

```
SockAddr1.sin_addr.S_addr := inet_addr(PAnsiChar(GetIPFromHostName('google.com')));
```

with

```
SockAddr1.sin_addr.S_addr :=
    inet_addr(PAnsiChar(AnsiString(GetIPFromHostName('google.com'))));
```

You may use one of the APIs designed for this purpose, like [`InternetCheckConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetcheckconnectiona#requirements), or [`InternetGetConnectedState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetconnectedstate), or [`INetworkListManager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager-getconnectivity) interface (Vista and later).

E.g.

```
const
  FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION = 1;
begin
  if not InternetCheckConnection('http://google.com', FLAG_ICC_FORCE_CONNECTION, 0) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
```

Comment: FYI, `InternetCheckConnection` and `InternetGetConnectedState` are notorious for being unreliable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you is right, +1. For example `InternetGetConnectedState` in my test, detect only if is connected to network adapter and not know nothing about internet signal.